# How do I manage security in my react app with rails API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, jwt, rails-api

I've been looking for some answers all day and I couldn't find anything that helped me.

I'm currently working on a platform developed in React and a Rails API. My Rails API is using devise-token to handle security and authentication (https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth).
I'm not using React-Redux.

The React frontend has public pages (such as a login) and private pages, where the login is required (a valid access-token).

I'm storing the access-token, uid and client in the session storage (these 3 parameters come from the login response), and the access-token is sent in the header on each request.

This is what I was thinking:

1. Once the user is logged in, store the response in the session storage and also in a javascript object. That object will be there unless the user refreshes the page, or closes and re-opens it.
2. Each time the user navigates to a private page, before react router returns the component, I will check if my LoggedInUser javascript object has something. If it doesn't have anything, I will call the "validate_token" endpoint with the session storage content, because it means that it's a returning user. If it's valid, save it in the javascript object called "LoggedInUser". If it's not, redirect to the login page.
3. If I don't have anything on my LoggedInUser object, or in the session storage, I will redirect to the login.

My questions is:

1. How can I make my private pages secure, if we are always talking about javascript variables and ajax calls (client-side)? A non-authorized user could debug my javascript file, create content in the "LoggedInUser" object, and see my private pages. The person won't be able to see any content because all requests with the non-valid token will return a 401, but they will still be able to see my HTML or static files, and the existing requests to the API.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make my private pages secure

If there are all bundled into your pkg, you cant. However, you could serve the templates, and load the data from the server only for authorized users.

Another option:

Host your private app on the server, and serve it only to permitted users. Webpack allows you to load particular modules when needed (lazy-loading). I believe, that with this technique you could prevent some modules to be served for unauthorized users.

But the logic must be done on the server side:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-load-react/